# Do something while waiting in input stream

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x, pipelining

I am transferring bytes from an inputstream to filechannel. As processor and file io are many time faster then network so its obvious that thread will pause many time while transferring data. Is it possible to implement pipelining concept for downloading files so that between every pause the thread processes the next get request So single thread is processing multiple get request? here is my simple implementation:

```
while (start < end && currentState.get() == 1) {
      delta = fileChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, start, 8192);
      start += delta;
      }
```

Any other ideas to improve speed are welcomed.

Comment: You need to look at [NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)). There are already techniques for asynchronous IO.

Comment: Do you realise that if you download two files at once, they'll probably both download half as fast?

Comment: Use Future, do useful tasks while you are still waiting for the value.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches:

1. Completely rewrite your code to an event-oriented paradigm (the best recourse is to use Netty for this);
2. employ Java's excellent support for multithreading. In this case you get to keep most of your blocking I/O code.